# Tikz element outside of boundingbox behind text

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

How can I have elements that protrudes outside of a `boundingbox' in a float and that overlaps with a text element in the page (paragraph/caption/header) be drawn behind it? In the example below I want the gray rectangle to be behind the paragraph of text.

Using tikz's `background` woun't do it. I tried finding some answer in the tikz manual but had no luck.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[2]

\begin{figure}[h]
\center

\caption{Some caption}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \useasboundingbox[draw] (0,0) rectangle (5,3);

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \path (1,1) [fill=black!10] rectangle (2,7);
    \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using  the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package; inside the figure a `ref` node was placed to locate the background material; the `pages=some` option was used with `\BgThispage` to add the material just for this page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pages=some,scale=1,angle=0]{background}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
  contents={\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\path (1,1) [fill=black!10] rectangle (2,7);},
  position={ref}
}

\begin{document}

\kant[2]
\begin{figure}[h]
\BgThispage
\centering
\caption{Some caption}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\useasboundingbox[draw] (0,0) rectangle (5,3);
\node (ref) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Let's say I have several such figures in a document, all floats. Could I still use this method? I tried having the backgroundsetup inside the figure environment to have the content definition follow the figure, but it didn't work.

Comment: I can redefine the content of the background just before every sucessive figure.